# How to efficiently retrieve total row count along with paginated results?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using pagination in my SQL Server query to limit the number of records returned at a time. I achieve this by providing `@PageSize` and `@PageNumber` variables to my query like so:

```sql
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

The front-end also needs to know the total number of rows (or pages) available. What's the most efficient way to get the total number of records that would be returned if I were not using pagination? Do I need to run a separate query without the `OFFSET..ROWS..FETCH NEXT..ROWS ONLY` clauses and simply `COUNT` the records?

Comment: There is no way to know the full count for certain without reading all the rows. The most efficient way is to not paginate using rownumbers in the first place. Use Keyset Pagination, it's much more efficient https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997

Comment: Depends on the query. If you're `SELECT`ing straight out of a table, without any filtering, then there is meta-data that can be used to efficiently get that information. But presumably your query is more complex than that.

Comment: [Optimising Server-Side Paging - Part II](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/optimising-server-side-paging-part-ii)

Answer (score -1):

I used CTE like so:

```sql
WITH [cte] AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS [TotalRows]
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE 1=1 -- and other criteria
)
SELECT *
FROM [cte]
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```